# SSH to raspberry pi fails with Operation timed out error

Tags: ssh

I have suddenly lost the ability to ssh into my raspberry pi.

the connection attempt hangs for sometime and eventually returns a "Operation timed out error".

SSH access is enabled on the Pi. The Port is set to 55555

I can successfully ping the Pi's IP address.

The verbose output of the ssh attempt is:

```
(base) kevin@KBurnham-MBP16 ~ % ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_pi pi@192.168.1.48 -p 55555 -vvv
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/kevin/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.1.48 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.48 [192.168.1.48] port 55555.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.48 port 55555: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.48 port 55555: Operation timed out
```

As I said, it was working fine, however, I ran and ansible playbook that may have changed some settings, I am unsure how to further troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: are you sure `192.168.1.48` is the pi? Just because something is there doesn't mean it's the pi (unless you have static IP set up or reserved the address in DHCP of course)

Comment: according to `hostname -I` that is the ip address. Is that sufficient to be sure?

Answer (score 1):

the aforementioned ansible playbook that I started but terminated had activated the firewall and restricted acceptable ports for ssh. Once I disabled it I was able to ssh as before.